# Two database on Postgres sever

Tags: postgresql

Can I have 2 databases in postgres server that has the same data, if yes how do I go about it?

I Currently have one database for work environment, but we are currently using it for training as well and we want to have 2 for training and work environment. I'm seeking help for solutions on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Just be sure to put something in place to prevent a mix-up between the two.

Comment: You can have as many databases as you want, with whatever you want in them. They're all independent. Have you actually tried anything? I would have assumed that was common knowledge if you work with databases. Anyway if you name them clearly e.g. "myapp_live" and "myapp_training" (and possibly create separate user accounts which have access to each one) then it should be possible to avoid any accidental confusion.

Comment: There is a maximum of 4,294,950,911 databases within a single PostgreSQL cluster. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/limits.html

Comment: Also, there is one more way apart from keeping separate DB names in same cluster... You can create one more cluster in the same server using the initdb utility - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html. Here you need to mention different port and different data directory. However, the server resources like RAM, Disk Space, etc will be shared between the 2 clusters. However, you can manage them separately in a lot of multiple aspects

Comment: Hy Frank thanks this helpful, Uhm lastly how do i copy the same data from "myapp_live" to "myapp_training"?

Comment: Back it up, and then restore it again, but with a different name. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html